# How can I generate a GUID in R?

Tags: r, random, guid, uuid

How can I generate GUIDs and UUIDs in R?

I would like to be able to generate GUIDs based on the hardware etc. of the machine running the rsession.

As a fallback, however, I would be happy to create UUIDs that comply with rfc4122.

Is there a package that can create GUIDs? Otherwise, does someone have some RFC4122 compatible UUID code lying about?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The optimal choice for this now is the `uuid` package.  It consists of one function (`UUIDgenerate`) that doesn't rely on R's internal random number generators and so doesn't suffer any consequences from using `set.seed` in a session as @thelatemail's answer does.  You can choose to have the UUID be generated either by the package's internal random number generator or based on time.

Comment: there appears to be a bug in the uuid package. Quite simply, if you generate a vector of uuids most of them will be duplicates.

Comment: @Matthew I think you may be doing something odd. Just tested this on MacOS with a vector of 1M UUIDs and had 1M uniques. No bug at all.

Comment: @Matthew They won't be duplicates, but they may be very similar. This is not a problem. [GUIDs are designed to be unique, not random.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120523-00/?p=7553/)

Answer (score 14):

I know nothing about the intricacies of UUID's, but would something like this do?

```
baseuuid <- paste(sample(c(letters[1:6],0:9),30,replace=TRUE),collapse="")

paste(
    substr(baseuuid,1,8),
    "-",
    substr(baseuuid,9,12),
    "-",
    "4",
    substr(baseuuid,13,15),
    "-",
    sample(c("8","9","a","b"),1),
    substr(baseuuid,16,18),
    "-",
    substr(baseuuid,19,30),
    sep="",
    collapse=""
)
# result like: "f7bd11ed-fca9-42e5-8c3e-4464cd02e0fa"
```

This should be in line with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid#Version_4_.28random.29

Comment: This is dangerous in the case of someone using set.seed.

Comment: @iShouldUseAName - I wouldn't really call it dangerous. All random functions in R are affected by set.seed, there's nowt I can do to change that.

Comment: @thelatemail you can use a tool that doesn't rely on R's internal random number generators/provide a warning with the answer.  This is almost certainly the superior answer now: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/uuid/index.html

Comment: @iShouldUseAName - it almost certainly is - feel free to post it as an answer. I can't time travel - `uuid` was  first released 7 months after this answer.

Comment: @thelatemail I wasn't suggesting you do :).  I know it was released after your answer hence the 'now' in "... the superior answer now".  Just adding that comment for future generations of R users looking for a solution.  I will add the `uuid` package solution as a separate answer.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using R in Unix environment, you can get UUID in R using `system()` command.

#### On Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS):

```
my_uuid <- system("uuid",intern=T)
my_uuid
[1] 0f62f1de-418d-11e3-8a19-cb0ceccb58ec
```

#### On Mac OS X 10.8:

```
my_uuid <- system("uuidgen", intern=T)
my_uuid
[1] 9A9D64DF-EB01-47E7-B16E-DC0343951883
```

Far as I know, both `uuid` and `uuidgen` follows [UUID Version 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid#Version_4_.28random.29) format.

Comment: Anything like this for windows/powershell ?

Answer (score 3):

Bioconductor had an Ruuid package that doesn't seem to be there anymore, but a google search on "Ruuid" will point to places that you can download it.

Comment: I assume this means that it is no longer being maintained? If so, I wonder if there would interested in revitalising it on R-forge?

Comment: Right. I just don't know why it was dropped out. It might have been simply that they didn't need it anymore - it was originally written for the 'graph' package as a way of uniquely identifying nodes. 

IIRC it embedded the libuuid software directly into the package as a way to avoid hassle for Windows users, perhaps there was a license issue there.

I suspect the former though. The last release was BioC 2.8 (last april) and it had nothing using it: http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.8/bioc/html/Ruuid.html

Comment: That version works out of the box for me on linux. IMO if there's interest, the polite thing to do would be to contact biocore and ask if they're cool with someone taking over the maintainer role. Otherwise, it is under the Artistic license which is fairly permissive.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer by @thelatemail for now, although yours is a better long term solution. I'll contact the maintainers when I have a little time.