# How to assign an unique ID, e.g., UUID for better project management in R?

Tags: r, project-management, uuid

I am looking for a better workaround than one I have to organize my projects in R language. Currently, I user [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com) IDE which gives a decent project management with versioning feature. I think default RStudio project management is good for me as long as results of analysis are intended for my work, i.e., I can keep track of results and data source using `.Rproj` in RStudio project environment, and reproduce results in future.

However, I also work with colleagues (biologists) in lab to do specific types of micro analysis or **tasks** using **the identical data source**. This creates several issues, e.g.,

- Running analysis for more than one task under the same RStudio project `.Rproj` file and potentially loosing track of which set of script files were used for a given task. Alternately, I can create task-specific .Rproj files but that is less preferable to me because I end up creating many R project directories. Also, `.Rproj` is RStudio IDE specific file. So, if I run R from console, I find it difficult to fetch one or more `.R` scripts used for one of those tasks under a parent project directory.
- Second and more important issue is when I pass results to a colleague and he/she returns to me after a year or so to rerun the same kind of analysis with few changes in analysis parameters. In most cases, I can not track simply by file names or data format as they have been reorganized as per his/her preference.

I thought to implement combination of user-defined project or task name, UUID and timestamp to define each of my project or tasks (subversions) within the same project. That way, I can pass this unique UUID along with results to colleague and preferably embed this UUID in results files/filenames for tracking and reproducibility in future.

I have made following workaround to assign a unique project ID. It has basically three scenarios.

#### Create an unique project ID for current working directory:

```
getwd()  
[1] "/home/foo/project1"  

project.id("Hello World")   
[1] "Project ID is: Hello World--0f62f1de-4187-11e3-89af-b7d1cb3029b4--30-Oct-2013-12-17-57-CDT"  
[1] "Project_ID file is at: /home/foo/project1/DO_NOT_DELETE_project_ID_30-Oct-2013-12-17-57-CDT.txt"
```

Prompt user for y/n if UUID already exists in the current working directory:

```
project.id("Project 2")  
[1] "Possible Project ID file(s) exists at: /home/foo/project1/"  
[1] "DO_NOT_DELETE_project_ID_30-Oct-2013-12-17-57-CDT.txt"
```

#### If user says no, command returns current project ID.

```
Do you want to make new subversion under this project? Say either yes or no: n  

[1] "Running project under the project ID: /home/foo/project1/DO_NOT_DELETE_project_ID_30-Oct-2013-12-17-57-CDT.txt"  
[1] "Project ID is: Hello World--0f62f1de-4187-11e3-89af-b7d1cb3029b4--30-Oct-2013-12-17-57-CDT"
```

#### If user says yes, command only modifies timestamp and outputs new `_<timestamp>_subversioned.txt` file. However, the latter file will keep the original user-defined project title and UUID created at beginning of the parent project.

```
Do you want to make new subversion under this project? Say either yes or no: y  

[1] "Project ID is: Hello World--0f62f1de-4187-11e3-89af-b7d1cb3029b4--30-Oct-2013-12-25-02-CDT--subversioned"  
[1] "SUBVERSIONED Project_ID file is at: /home/foo/project1/DO_NOT_DELETE_project_ID_30-Oct-2013-12-25-02-CDT_subversioned.txt"   
[1] "Previous Project ID file(s) exists at: /home/foo/project1/DO_NOT_DELETE_project_ID_30-Oct-2013-12-17-57-CDT.txt"  

Warning message:  
In project.id("Project 2") :  
  Possible Project ID file(s) exists at: /home/foo/project1/DO_NOT_DELETE_project_ID_30-Oct-2013-12-17-57-CDT.txt
```

---

I think my script (below) is a complicated way of keeping project management simpler! However, I like to see if I can use task-specific UUID to track analyses shared with lab colleagues.

Thanks,
Sam

---

### R script: Assign an unique project UUID:

```
project.id <- function (project_title = as.character()) {
  chk_id_file <- list.files(path=getwd(),pattern="DO_NOT_DELETE_project_ID",recursive=F,ignore.case=F)
  if(length(chk_id_file) == 0) {
    stitle <- ifelse(is.na(project_title[1]), readline("Provide short project title: "), project_title)
    tstamp <- format(Sys.time(),"%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M-%S-%Z")
    projid <- paste(as.character(stitle),system("uuid",intern=T),tstamp,sep="--")
    fname <- paste0("DO_NOT_DELETE_project_ID_",tstamp,".txt")
    write.table(projid,fname,quote=F,row.names=F,col.names=F)
    print(paste0("Project ID is: ",projid))
    print(paste0("Project_ID file is at: ",getwd(),"/",fname))
  }
  else 
{    print(paste0("Possible Project ID file(s) exists at: ",getwd(),"/"))
    print(chk_id_file)

    uprompt1 <- readline("Do you want to make new subversion under this project? Say either yes or no: ")
    if (grepl("y",uprompt1,ignore.case=T)) {
      warning(paste0("Possible Project ID file(s) exists at: ",getwd(),"/",chk_id_file))
      subtitle <- readLines(paste0(getwd(),"/",chk_id_file[1]))
      library(stringr)
      stitle <- str_extract(string=subtitle,".*[a-z0-9]{12}")
      tstamp <- format(Sys.time(),"%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M-%S-%Z")
      projid <- paste(as.character(stitle),tstamp,"subversioned",sep="--")
      fname <- paste0("DO_NOT_DELETE_project_ID_",tstamp,"_subversioned.txt")
      write.table(projid,fname,quote=F,row.names=F,col.names=F)
      print(paste("Project ID is: ",projid,sep=""))
      print(paste0("SUBVERSIONED Project_ID file is at: ",getwd(),"/",fname))
      print(paste0("Previous Project ID file(s) exists at: ",getwd(),"/",chk_id_file))
    }
    else {
      parentprojid <- grep("subversioned",chk_id_file,invert=T)
      parentprojid_read <- readLines(paste0(getwd(),"/",chk_id_file[parentprojid]))
      print(paste0("Running project under the project ID: ",getwd(),"/",chk_id_file[parentprojid]))
      print(paste0("Project ID is: ",parentprojid_read))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10493590/1188479

Comment: Yes! That is one way of assigning UUID. I use system("uuid") instead. However, the bigger issue as Spacedman mentioned is organizing and distributing unique project or task ids with research collaborators.

Answer (score 1):

Get a corporate git repository or other enterprise version control system and make sure colleagues all use it. Then every analysis gets tagged in git and the tag added to documentation. Redoing last years analysis is just a matter of checking out that tag from the repo and running.

This question smells like a very big problem and probably off-topic for here.

Comment: I forgot to mention but my colleagues are biologists and not familiar with github or other coding platforms, including R. Most of times, they get tab-delimited or excel spreadsheets or graphical output from analyses that I or other bioinformaticians do. Problem arises when I get re-analysis request from them based on the analysis results I gave them months-year back. If I have uuid-tagged results file or analysis directory, then I guess it is easier to track that project directory in my system.

Comment: Okay, I thought they were working on the code too. If its only you, then use git and use git's commit tags for UUIDs.