# Create Unique ID

Tags: r, hash, primary-key

In R, Which is the best way to create a unique ID for an object, persisting across sessions? I am creating R6 class objects, and I want to provide each a unique ID, stored as a member variable, ie, `1, 2, 3, .... n` or a hex code, or whatever. If two objects are created at EXACTLY the same time, then they should still have unique ID's. I could create an option with my package, that gets incremented each time the base R6 is instantiated, but then this gets reset next time the package is loaded. I am sure this has been covered somewhere, so, someone, please just put a link in the comment if you can steer me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It would require some serialization on your end, but the networkDynamic package has `persistent.ids` functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at GUID, cf. for instance:
[How can I generate a GUID in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492817/how-can-i-generate-a-guid-in-r)
and `uuid` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/uuid/index.html