# How to Generate 112000 UUID in R

Tags: r, uuid

I want to generate n numbers of random uuid.

I have tried using

```
# Generate one id
uuid()

# Or a bunch
uuid(10)
```

Does any one have any quick `R` code for this?

Comment: What is `uuid()`?

Comment: I presume Unique User ID?

Comment: `sample` might help. You can randomly sample from a specified range of values with or without replacement

Comment: What about `sample.int(1, 10)` for unique integer random number generator ?

Comment: @VitaliAvagyan which package do it come from ? Without knowing that, answering is just guessing. You be done with a `do.call` on a list for example

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  `uuid` package. There are [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492817/how-can-i-generate-a-guid-in-r).

```
> library(uuid)
> 
> set.seed(357)
> replicate(10, UUIDgenerate())
 [1] "2ee63f9a-12f4-45b7-9e44-d20623f2c6c5"
 [2] "6c8c5f63-b177-485d-9463-d44edff65ba7"
 [3] "4ef747bb-e100-4119-be6a-754bf0142f92"
 [4] "6c3bde0f-a494-410d-8b6e-104e971f04fa"
 [5] "04bc1b0b-f2ff-4901-95b8-b9c6b9b1ec77"
 [6] "dbea25bf-24b4-49cb-a09c-ef4098ae1566"
 [7] "c1ceefa8-fad2-412a-8496-6549ef31f418"
 [8] "92162470-e390-44db-900e-7d9a206264da"
 [9] "6fc8cba9-d99d-4b30-a217-7e662ed91fa5"
[10] "166f0131-d881-41d9-a093-b438d07992a5"
```